# 9 DoF Sensor Accelerometer Readings Inconsistent

Tags: arduino-uno, i2c, accelerometer

I have the following sensor stick: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10724

It has an accelerometer, gyroscope, and magnetometer.

I have connected it to an arduino and am reading the accelerometer values while the sensor is completely flat and the values jump all over the place:

ie
0
2
3
7
-5
12
35
-3
...

This is how I am reading them:

```
void Accel_Init()
{
  Wire.beginTransmission(ACCEL_ADDRESS);
  Wire.write(0x2D);  // Power register
  Wire.write(0x08);  // Measurement mode
  Wire.endTransmission();
  delay(5);
  Wire.beginTransmission(ACCEL_ADDRESS);
  Wire.write(0x31);  // Data format register
  Wire.write(0x08);  // Set to full resolution
  Wire.endTransmission();
  delay(5);

  // Because our main loop runs at 50Hz we adjust the output data rate to 50Hz (25Hz bandwidth)
  Wire.beginTransmission(ACCEL_ADDRESS);
  Wire.write(0x2C);  // Rate
  Wire.write(0x09);  // Set to 50Hz, normal operation
  Wire.endTransmission();
  delay(5);
}

// Reads x, y and z accelerometer registers
void Read_Accel()
{
  int i = 0;
  byte buff[6];

  Wire.beginTransmission(ACCEL_ADDRESS); 
  Wire.write(0x32);  // Send address to read from
  Wire.endTransmission();

  Wire.beginTransmission(ACCEL_ADDRESS);
  Wire.requestFrom(ACCEL_ADDRESS, 6);  // Request 6 bytes
  while(Wire.available())  // ((Wire.available())&&(i<6))
  { 
    buff[i] = Wire.read();  // Read one byte
    i++;
  }
  Wire.endTransmission();

  if (i == 6)  // All bytes received?
  {
    // No multiply by -1 for coordinate system transformation here, because of double negation:
    // We want the gravity vector, which is negated acceleration vector.
    accel[0] = (((int) buff[3]) << 8) | buff[2];  // X axis (internal sensor y axis)
    accel[1] = (((int) buff[1]) << 8) | buff[0];  // Y axis (internal sensor x axis)
    accel[2] = (((int) buff[5]) << 8) | buff[4];  // Z axis (internal sensor z axis)
  }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong that these values aren't the same?

Comment: What does your circuit look like? That may help...

Comment: Its just the arduino and sensor...

sda -> pin A4 && scl -> pin A5

Comment: What values do you get when you do shake it?

Answer (score 2):

In 'FULL_RES' mode the number you get is amount of 4mg units.

So 1 is 4mg, 2 is 8mg, -4 = -32mg.

Also note that your current code doesn't interpret the first bit (so the 13th from the right) as the sign bit, so you'll never get negative values. ([Question related to this](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/3401/bit-mask-first-2-bits-of-16-bits-for-accelerometer))

PS I think it is actually more like 3.9mg.

Comment: How do I go about interpreting it as the sign bit?

Comment: Like I said, just follow the link in my answer. Basically just shift left 5 positions and then divide by 32. (`accel[0] = (accel[0]<<5)/32`)